# Android, BottomNavigationView, set weight for each item?

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I am using Bottom navigation bar in my app. It contains 3 items as in below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="9">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3" />
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:backgroundTint="#f5f5f5"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here there is the "@menu/navigation" code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="Button1"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="Button2"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="Button3"/>

</menu>
```

Now I want to somehow have the middle button take half the space provided and the other two share the other half. But no weight attribute is present. In other words, I want to set the layout weight for the button2 to 2 and for the button1 and button3 to 1. Is there a way to do this?

Any help or tips is appreciated.

Below are the shapes that might help:

Current layout:

[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0k3q.jpg)

MY goal is to change it like this:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTFZe.jpg)

Comment: can you post image design ??

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Looking for changing the width myself

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:
you can use an layout to replace the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_page_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button

            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="your drawable"
             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="your text" />

    </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_page_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button

            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="your drawable"
             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="your text" />

    </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_page_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button

            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="your drawable"
             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="your text" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and height is flexable and you can new a new xml to write this as bottom Navigation and then include to your LinearLayout.

In Java class you can implement onclick listener.